# Query By Example. find passenger who have bought two same ticket

Tags: mysql, oracle

Schema:

Flight (Flight_Id, Date, From, To)

Passenger (Passenger_Name, Gender)

Ticket (Ticket_Id, Flight_Id, Passenger_Name, Class, Price)

I know how to find passenger who have bought more than one ticket. But don't know how to find passenger who have bought only two ticket.

[image]

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for as you have tagged it for both MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: Sorry, You guys see my picture ?

Comment: It is Query by Example

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/cZiFX.png

Answer (score 0):

Two Tickets
select Passenger_Name
FROM Ticket t INNER JOIN Passenger p
on p.Passenger_Name=t.Passenger_Name
GROUP BY Passenger_Name
HAVING COUNT(1)=2;

More than One Ticket

select Passenger_Name
FROM Ticket t INNER JOIN Passenger p
on p.Passenger_Name=t.Passenger_Name
GROUP BY Passenger_Name
HAVING COUNT(1)>1;

Answer (score 0):

If you want passengers who have bought exactly two tickets for a flight then:

```
SELECT   Passenger_Name,
         Flight_Id
FROM     Ticket
GROUP BY Passenger_Name,
         Flight_Id
HAVING   COUNT( Ticket_Id ) = 2;
```

If you want passengers who have bought more than one ticket for a flight then:

```
SELECT   Passenger_Name,
         Flight_Id
FROM     Ticket
GROUP BY Passenger_Name,
         Flight_Id
HAVING   COUNT( Ticket_Id ) > 1;
```